# GNUPLOT contour over splot with pm3d from different data files

Tags: gnuplot, contour

i am struggling in trying to splot a nonuniform binary matrix from a datafile1, and plot over it a contour of another variable, over the same grid but another datafile. Both the datafiles are in binary matrix shape.

```
    # CONTOUR SETTINGS
    set contour surface
    set cntrparam level discrete 0.3,0.067
    # PRINT CONTOUR ON TABLE
    set table 'tablefile_contour'
    splot 'contour_variable_field_binary' binary with l lt -1
    unset table
    # FIELD SPLOT
    set view map;
    splot 'field_to_be_plotted_2D_binary' binary with pm3d,\
          'tablefile_contour' u 1:2:3 w p lt -1
```

basically i have been trying to follow some recipes fished along the internet.
If I try to plot only the splot, i obtain a 2D pic. I want to put on it isolines from the 'contour_variable_field_binary' file, so i splot it on a table file and i splot it together with the field to be plotted. I do it, i obtain a black pic. 
How can i superimpose isolines from another file? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my suggestion is a bit too long for a comment:

Have you tried plotting both original files together? You can disable contouring of the first file using `nocontour`, and disable the surface for the second plot with `nosurface`:

```
set contour base
set cntrparam level discrete 0.3,0.067

set pm3d map
splot 'field_to_be_plotted_2D_binary' binary with pm3d nocontour,\
      'contour_variable_field_binary' binary with l lt nosurface
```

Can't tell if this works properly because I have not data for testing.

Comment: Christoph, This is not the first time you save my day about gnuplot. This is the time to reveal your real identity, Gnuplotman. You cannot hide yourself behind your plotted mask for too long!