# Contour over 3D plot, two different data zranges

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to 3Dplot one data set, and contour plot a different dataset into a single combined plot. (The contour dataset is related with gradients of the 3Dplot, for those interested). The code adapted [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525002/gnuplot-contour-over-splot-with-pm3d-from-different-data-files) works OK, except in one respect: if I use `set zrange` to scale my 3D plot, contours disappear. Autoranged 3Dplot does not look good, although contours appear OK then, that's why I'd like to apply a custom range. I suspect the problem has something to do with the contours getting ranged, too, in a way that leaves no contour left. But I'm not experienced enough with Gnuplot to see whether this is really the case, or how to solve the problem.

This code...

```
    reset
    set ztics 5
    #set zrange [10 : 25] #nowriteback
    set view 135,60
    set contour base #surface
    set cntrlabel font ",7"
    set datafile missing "NaN"
    set clabel
    
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 1.5
    splot 'out011_Io.txt' nonuniform matrix with lines notitle nocontour, \
    'out011_FlxN.txt' nonuniform matrix with lines title "{/Symbol F}_{N}" enhanced nosurface
```

...creates this plot: excessively flattened 3D plot with OK contours [image],

while activating the zrange...

```
reset
set ztics 5
set zrange [10 : 25] #nowriteback
set view 135,60
set contour base #surface
set cntrlabel font ",7"
set datafile missing "NaN"
set clabel

set cntrparam levels discrete 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 1.5
splot 'out011_Io.txt' nonuniform matrix with lines notitle nocontour, \
'out011_FlxN.txt' nonuniform matrix with lines title "{/Symbol F}_{N}" enhanced nosurface
```

...creates this plot: good 3D plot, no visible contours.

[image]

Original data can be found here: [out011_FlxN.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArZEGod1e1Xlrhqfr6jAUh9AdweP?e=SeeIEX) and [out011_Io.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArZEGod1e1Xlrhl7SVzIvHLAguGJ?e=jCcTbh)

Suggestions from more knowledgeable are highly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot fully reproduce the first graph with your data and your given code. I do not see any contour in the first graph. Which version of gnuplot do you use?

Comment: your data values of `out011_FlxN.txt` are in the range of approx 10 to 180. How should gnuplot be able to plot contour lines for levels between 0.3 to 1.5? Something must be confused with your data or your levels.

Comment: @theozh, the data you refer to is with the number 10 added, for the first hack suggested by Joce. My original data (without the 10 added, i.e. the SHIFT variable used insted) is found in the [link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArZEGod1e1Xlrhqfr6jAUh9AdweP?e=SeeIEX).

Comment: I will need to go through the code carefully to see whether I understand how it works, but the plot looks gorgeous. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `help contour`, gnuplot offers the options to plot the contour

```
set contour {base | surface | both}
```

Unfortunately, not at a custom level as you requested.
So, my suggestion for a workaround would be the following:

1. plot the data and the contour into a table, e.g. datablock `$Cont`. This datablock will contain the data and the contour lines (in your case 5) and each sub-block separated by 2 empty lines.
2. unset contour
3. plot `$Cont`, but except the first block. In your case via `index 1:5`.

Explanation of:

```
for [i=1:LevelCount] $Cont u 1:2:(10):(column(-2)) index i w l lc var ti columnhead(3)
```

Plotting the blocks 1 to 5 of `$Cont` at a constant z-level `(10)` using variable color `lc var` determined by pseudocolumn `(column(-2))` with `columnhead(3)` as keytitle. Apparently, in your case there are only 4 contour lines, i.e. none at `0.3`.

**Code:**

```
### contour plot at custom level
reset session

set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 1.5
set table $Cont
    splot "out011_FlxN2.txt" nonuniform matrix
unset table
unset contour
 
set key at screen 0.16, screen 1 title "{/Symbol F}_{N}"
set view 135,60
set xyplane relative 0
LevelCount = 5

splot "out011_Io.txt" nonuniform matrix w l notitle, \
      for [i=1:LevelCount] $Cont u 1:2:(10):(column(-2)) index i w l lc var ti columnhead(3) 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal example including datafiles, it's difficult to answer for sure, but it could be because your second file has values outside the `zrange` you would like to impose for the first one. E.g., the code:

```
set cntrparam levels discrete -.5,.5
set contour base
splot 10*(sin(x/3)*sin(y/3)+2), sin(x/3)*sin(y/3) nosurface
```

does produce contours, but there too if you specify a `zrange` which does not include `-0.5` and possibly `0.5`, these contours are not shown. Since there is no `axes` keyword for `splot` (contrary to `plot`), to the best of my knowledge you're left with tricks to make the data in the second file fit in the range of the data of the 1st. Since the range of the 1st is `[10:25]` and the one of the second `[0.3:1.5]`, adding `10` is good. But then you have to produce key "by hand", else the contours would be labelled `10.3, 10.4,...`. Here is the corrected code:

```
reset
set ztics 5
set zrange [10 : 25] #nowriteback
set view 135,60
set contour base #surface
set cntrlabel font ",7"
set datafile missing "NaN"
set clabel

NSURFACES=1 #change if plotting more surfaces
SHIFT=10
LEVELS="10.3, 10.4, 10.6, 11.0, 11.5"
set cntrparam levels discrete @LEVELS
set style line 100 lc rgb "white"
splot 'out011_Io.txt' nonuniform matrix with lines notitle nocontour, \
  'out011_FlxN.txt' nonuniform matrix using 1:2:($3+SHIFT) with lines notitle enhanced nosurface, \
  for [i=0:words(LEVELS)] 1/0 w l ls (i==0)?100:i+NSURFACES  title (i==0)?"{/Symbol F}_{N}":sprintf(("%.1f"),word(LEVELS,i)-SHIFT)
```

NB:

1. A cleaner solution would be to use `stats` on both and calculate what offset should be added to the 2nd file rather than hardsetting 10.
2. From version 5.2, you can replace `1/0` by the cleaner `keyentry` keyword.

Comment: This is a clever hack, ugly but will do what's needed. Thanks for suggesting it. On my first attempt the code did not produce the contours, however, although I agree it should. I'm working on it, but in the mean time, my numerical data files are found as [link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArZEGod1e1Xlrhi7GatQc9G3JhLe?e=rbEy2e) and [link](https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArZEGod1e1Xlrhl7SVzIvHLAguGJ?e=jCcTbh) .

Comment: That was my mistake: now using `@LEVELS` in `set cntrparam` prevent `gnuplot` from converting string to float before evaluating command. Contours should show now. Btw, have you updated your graident file adding 10 everywhere? It's better to have a using in plot command, adding it (it was my mistake in answer), use `SHIFT=0` if your file is pre-shifted.

Comment: This works, great, thanks! I'll need to go to the user manual to make sure I understand the syntax used. Namely there is now another issue: the colors of the contour legend do not match with the actual contours. The plot I got is like [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArZEGod1e1XlrhuIykHMqVjk8jvP?e=MxTt49). Contour data looks like [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArZEGod1e1XlrhyU47ppg8dMsB3c?e=dQOo9i), so there are actually no <0.3 values, and the innermost contour should be <0.4 which is light-green in the plot but red in the legend. Next <0.6 cntr is yellow in the plot but orange in the legend.

Comment: It seems my Gnuplot v5.2 uses linetype 4 for the **rightmost** level specified in the `set cntparam level discrete` statement, which is also found in the data-to-be-contoured. And it uses linetypes 5, 6, 7... for the contours towards the left/beginning of the `set cntparam level discrete`, as long as the level is also found in the data-to-be-contoured. Contrary to the above, in the legend Gnuplot uses linetypes 2, 3, 4 ... , starting from the **leftmost** value of the `set cntparam level discrete`, whether the level is found in the data or not.

Comment: If I verify that the `set cntparam discrete` contains no levels that are not found in the data-to-be-contoured, and replace the `...(i==0)?100:i+NSURFACES  title (i==0)?"{/Symbol F}_{N}"...` by `...(i==0)?100:NSURFACES+words(LEVELS)+3-i  title (i==0)?"{/Symbol F}_{N}"...`, the legend is plotted correctly. The indexing scheme reverse engineered here sort-of agrees with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878163/gnuplot-contour-line-color-set-style-line-and-set-linetype-not-working).

Comment: Oh, I hadn't checked that indeed. Well then if it's to be robust at all, a passage by `stats` is needed, discarding any `LEVELS` not present in the data and calculating the `SHIFT`. I'll see if I find time to edit answer to do this.